# Realm filter firstDate older then newDate

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nsdate

I am trying to get the objects from realm, where `newDate` is later then `firstDate`. So if the date from `firstDate` is 05.10.2017, it will get objects after that date, example 06.10.2017, but not 04.10.2017.

This is how I am storing the date:

```
class User: Object {
    @objc dynamic var firstDate = Date()
    @objc dynamic var newDate = Date()
}
```

This is how I am saving the objects:

```
let date = Date()
let realm = try! Realm()
let myUser = User()

myUser.firstDate = self.date
```

This is how I am trying to retrieve the objects:

```
var userData: Results<User>?
if (homeIndexPathRow == 0) {
    let getData = realm.objects(User.self).filter("firstDate > newDate")
    userData = getData
    print("userData", userData!)
}
```

When trying to retrieve the objects, the app crashes.. Is it something wrong with the filter format?

Comment: Don't do force unwrapping on a value that can be `nil`. Are you sure the data actually contains some entries which the filter should return?

Comment: @DávidPásztor It should contain entries. I have opened the realm file in Realm Browser, and got this: https://image.ibb.co/fSoxdw/Screen_Shot_2017_10_06_at_03_02_58.png So as you can see, it should be just fine(?) Left is `firstDate` and right is `newDate`.

Comment: There are no entries for which `firstDate > newDate`, so `getData` is `nil` as expected...

Comment: You say that your app crashes... care to share any information at all about the crash?..

Comment: @bdash Error message is only: `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor How do you suggest I do this then? To get all the object created after `firstData` date?

Comment: @AntonDiablo you should change the relation sign in your filter. Moreover, if `firstDate` will stay the same for all objects, you shouldn't persist it in Realm and definitely shouldn't store it in every single object.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Why shouldn't I store it in every single object? `firstDate` is only for the first objects added at first launch. Objects added later then first launch will not have `firstDate `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var yourNSDate = NSDate()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstDate < %@", yourNSDate)
let dataResults = realm.objects(User.self).filter(predicate)
userData = dataResults
```

Replace that with the code below `if (homeIndexPathRow == 0) { ...`